# Violación de segmento ('Core' generado)

Tags: c++

estoy ejecutando el siguiente programa que pretende construir un objeto eval a partir de un objeto program con una serie de parámetros, entre ellos un par key-value que es "Const"-5.0. Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo obtengo siempre el mismo error de violación de segmento. Tengo entendido que dicho error se debe normalmente a un intento de acceso a una zona de memoria que no corresponde, sin embargo no logro ver donde podría estar este fallo.

La línea de código en la cual falla el programa es dentro de la función execute() al hacer int ret = eval->execute();. El objeto eval tiene implementada otra función también llamada execute a la que llamo desde ahí, y sin embargo no puedo acceder a ella...

Alguien sabe porque?

```
int main(){
 program *prog = create_program(); 
 int inputs2[] = {};
 append_expression(prog, 2, "", "Const", inputs2, 0);
 add_op_param_double(prog, "value", 5);
 evaluation *eval = build(prog);
 int dim = 0;
 size_t *shape = nullptr;
 ndouble *data = nullptr;
 if (execute(eval, &dim, &shape, &data) != 0)
 {
    printf("evaluation fails\n");
    return -1;
 }

 if (dim == 0)
    printf("res = %f\n", data[0]);
 else
    printf("result as tensor is not supported yet\n");

 return 0;}

int program::add_op_param_double(
 const char *key, double value) {
 std::map<std::string, double> m;
 std::string s(key);
 for(int i = 0; i < this->expr_.size(); i++){
     if(this->expr_[i].op_type == "Const" && this->expr_[i].op_name == "value"){
        m[s] = value;
        this->kv.push_back(m);
        printf("value from expression %f\n", m[s]);

    }
 } 

 return 0;}


int execute(
 evaluation *eval,
 int *p_dim,
 size_t **p_shape,
 double **p_data){
  printf("evaluation %p, p_dim %p, p_shape %p, p_data %p\n",
    eval, p_dim, p_shape, p_data);
  int ret = eval->execute();
  if (ret != 0)
    return ret;
  *p_dim = 0;
  *p_shape = nullptr;
  *p_data = &eval->get_result();
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;}
```

Update, esto es lo que hace la función de build:

```
evaluation *build(program *prog){
 evaluation *eval = prog->build();
 printf("evaluation %p\n", eval);
 return eval;}

evaluation *program::build(){
 evaluation *eval = new evaluation(this->expr_);
 return eval;}
```

Update:

```
program *create_program() {
 program *prog = new program;
 printf("program %p\n", prog);
 return prog;}

evaluation *build(program *prog){
 evaluation *eval = prog->build();
 printf("evaluation %p\n", eval);
 printf("PASO 3: EVALUACIÓN CONSTRUIDA\n");

 return eval;}

evaluation *program::build(){
 evaluation *eval = new evaluation(this->expr_);
 return eval;}
```

Tanto el objeto program como el eval tienen de atributos:

```
std::vector<expression> expr_;
std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> kv;
```

Además el objeto eval tiene un atributo double result

El objeto expression tiene de atributos:

```
int expr_id;
std::string op_name;
std::string op_type;
int *inputs;
int num_inputs;
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace la instrucción `build(prog)`?

Comment: Build(prog) crea un nuevo objeto eval en el que se copian las expresiones que contiene inicialmente el objeto de tipo programa prog.

Comment: Muy probablemente esa función lo esté haciendo mal, devolviendo un puntero incorrecto... no lo puedo asegurar sin ver su cuerpo.

Comment: Acabo de actualizarlo incluyendo el cuerpo

Comment: Tu código es tremendamente espagueti. ¿Qué es el objeto `evaluation`? ¿Qué contiene?

Comment: El objeto evaluation contiene un vector de expresiones de distintos tipos, uno de los cuales es el de tipo "Const" como la expresión que se añade con la función append_expression dentro del mail(). Con estas expresiones, dependiendo del tipo que sean, se quiere obtener un resultado que es un atributo del objeto eval. Con "Const" el resultado es simplemente devolver el valor de la constante, en este caso 5.0. En tercer lugar el objeto eval tiene un atributo kv que es un vector de tipo Map que contiene pares key value con siendo la key "value" y el value 5.0. Se usa para devolver el resultado

Comment: Chachi, pero eso no da pistas de por qué falla. El fallo no está en lo que crees que hace si no en lo que está haciendo en realidad. Sin ver el código no puedo más que conjeturar.

Comment: He vuelto a editar, a ver si ahora puedes verlo mejor.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, no hace falta que conjetures más, gracias :)

Comment: Tal y como tienes el código, raro será que no encuentres más problemas. El uso y abuso de punteros, código espagueti y encapsulación mal entendida es propenso a errores.

Comment: Es lo que tiene acabar de empezar a aprender, que se hace despacio y poco a poco. Pero bueno, no le molestó más. Chao

Comment: No es molestia :) ese código que muestras no se parece en nada a algo a lo que un principiante debiera acercarse.

Comment: De ahí quizás mi confusión :)